# Rigidbody velocity is zero sometimes while the rigidbody is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to add sound to my pushable object and just have a simple if statement for checking if the pushable object is moving. The concept is quite simple, if the object is moving the sound should play and when it's not moving it shouldn't. The problem however is, that when I debug the value there is a 0 every 5 frames or so. This causes the sound to work inconsistently. The script I have is really simple, and I have tried changing to fixedupdate, but it didn't work. I had read somewhere that physics calculations are done in fixedUpdate.

```
public class PushableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    AudioSource audioS;

    bool rbIsMoving = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        audioS = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (rb.velocity == Vector3.zero)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not moving");
            audioS.volume = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Moving");
            audioS.volume = 0.1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I have just figured out that if the player pushes the pushable object into the wall the sound is still playing, for this reason I think I have to change the way too determine if the object is moving or not.

Answer (score 4):

This happens due to [single precision floating point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

You never (should) compare two `float` values directly since they might logically be equal (e.g. `1 = 5*0.2`) but for the computer they might be different by a small "epsilon"

So Unity decides that `Vector3` simply uses only a precision of `0.00001` for equality for [==](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html)

---

Rather use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) which uses a very small [Epsilon](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) instead.

---

Than easier than comparing each component of the `rb.velocity` against `0` what you actually want is the [`rb.velocity.magnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html) which is actually the overall speed.

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(rb.velocity.magnitude, 0))
```

---

**Update**

Alternatively store the last position and compare it to the current one using [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) either again with `Mathf.Approximately`

```
private Vector3 lastPosition;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if(Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Distance(lastPosition, transform.position), 0))
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
        lastPosition = transform.positiom;
    }
}
```

Or with a custom threshold

```
if(Vector3.Distance(lastPosition, transform.position) <= someThreshold)
```

or this time you actually can use `==` if a threshold of `0.00001` is what you want

```
if(lastPosition == transform.position)
```

Comment: For some reason the stuttering of the sound is still happening, I do however get the idea behind this. Is is possible to change the range? i.e. something like between -0.1 and 0.1?

Comment: See my update for comparing to the last position instead. There you can add a threshold

Comment: Thanks for the indepth explenation, but for some reason the sound stuttering persists. This is weird as if the position is checked multiple times a frame or something.

Comment: You could try to use it in `LateUpdate` instead. This way it would be asured that it is always done after all Physics and user interaction are done already

Comment: I have just tried using LateUpdate, but unfortunately without any succes. The weird thing is that while the pushable object is moving, it still returns every now and again as if it is not moving. i.e. lastPosition and currentPosition are the same. Would it be possible to do something like when the lastPos and currentPos are the same for x frames than the volume should be 0?

Comment: well sure you can do that by simply having a `private int counter` and count it up while not moving. But it is hard to tell what exactly is not working correctly there without having your project. It sounds like the original problem comes from the object been moved to an "invalid" position and "jumping" back from a collider. You should rather try to avoid that moving completely if it would result in an invalid position

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine, to be honest there is not much special going on thusfar. It's just a cube with a rigidbody, but I think I know what the problem is. The player is characterController based and is not using a rigidbody. I think for this reason the pushing works a bit jittery. How would something with the int counter work? I haven't used something like that yet.

Comment: After some more experimenting I have figured something out.The script is actually working correctly, but since the pushable object is moving so slow it is sometimes standing still for like a frame if this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the RigidBody is sleeping:

```
if (!rb.IsSleeping()
{
//it's moving
}
else
{
//it's not
}
```

Or check if the transform position has moved since last frame:

```
Vector3 lastposition;
Gameobject go = somegameobject; 

function Update()
{
    if (lastposition == go.transform.position)
    {
     //not moving
    }
    else
    {
     //moving
    }
    lastposition = go.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Ha, I didn't know this, but it still registers when the player is colliding. In my game the player has to press a button to push, so it's not quite yet working.

Comment: You can also store the coordinates of the transform in variables and check if they are changing in Update/FixedUpdate.  If they are the same as last frame then the object is not moving, else it is moving.

Comment: I have currently slightly changed the if statement to also check if the player is holding the pushing button. When I push the object into a wall the pushable object isn't moving but the sound is still player, I think due to holding the pushing button and because the rigidbody isn't sleeping anymore. How would I check if the position has changed like in your comment?

Comment: Updated my answer with position comparision.

Comment: Both answers are regarding the same technique now, thank you for the helpful insights!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transform.hasChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html) to check if the player position has changed on the last update

```
        if (!this.transform.hasChanged)
        {
            print("Player is not moving");
        }
        transform.hasChanged = false;
```